# didDeselectRowAtIndexPath not called from UITableViewController added to UIViewController from story board

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

I am using a split view controller and wanting to add multiple table views to the master view controller.

So I can take advantage of prototype cells that (I believe) you can only get from UITableViewController I have put the UITableViewController into a second storyboard for the app.  I am then substantiating it with:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SecondStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MyTableViewController *myTableViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

I then add the view of this UITableViewController as a subview of my UIViewController.

```
[self.view addSubview:myTableViewController.view];
```

When I run this, I can select and highlight rows just fine.  But didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not being called for some reason?

Thanks for any help,
Richard

Comment: Did you set the `delegate` property of the `UITableView`?

Comment: I have checked in the storyboard and the delegate for the UITableView is setup correctly.  Must be something in the way I have added the UITableViewController to the UIViewController that is blocking the call I guess.  But is receiving touch events, as I said, because the rows are highlighting as expected when touched.

Comment: Where do you set the property? I once had the problem by setting the delegate to a table view in the `init` method. But you have to do it after the view has been loaded, so `viewDidLoad` would be the right place. Just to make sure this isn't the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line

`myTableViewController.view.delegate = myTableViewController;`

or Make sure you have done the same in XIB(Interface Builder).

Comment: I could not find any myTableViewController.view.delegate property.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I needed to add the uitableviewcontroller as a child controller of the uiviewcontroller as well.  Just adding the view alone was not enough.